# UINavigationBar with Category, Act as Button too

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, button, uinavigationbar

in my iphone app, im trying to make my uinavigationbar act as a button, i mean do something when i touch it. Not back button o any nav item, the bar itself.
heres how i "categorized" it:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIImage *img    = [UIImage imageNamed: @"bar.png"];
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    self.tintColor = color;
}
```

The action would be navigate to some view..
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I used a category because i thought i was the only way to achieve this customization of the UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use categories to override methods from a class.  From the [Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html) guide:

> Although the language currently allows
>   you to use a category to override
>   methods the class inherits, or even
>   methods declared in the class
>   interface, you are strongly
>   discouraged from using this
>   functionality. A category is not a
>   substitute for a subclass. There are
>   several significant shortcomings:
>
> - When a category overrides an inherited
>     method, the method in the category
>     can, as usual, invoke the inherited
>     implementation via a message to super.
>     However, if a category overrides a
>     method that already existed in the
>     category's class, there is no way to
>     invoke the original implementation.
> - A category cannot reliably override
>     methods declared in another category
>     of the same class. This issue is of
>     particular significance since many of
>     the Cocoa classes are implemented
>     using categories. A framework-defined
>     method you try to override may itself
>     have been implemented in a category,
>     and so which implementation takes
>     precedence is not defined.
> - The very presence of some methods may
>     cause behavior changes across all
>     frameworks. For example, if you add an
>     implementation of windowWillClose: to
>     NSObject, this will cause all window
>     delegates to respond to that method
>     and may modify the behavior of all
>     instances of NSWindow instances. This
>     may cause mysterious changes in
>     behavior and can lead to crashes.

Instead, you might be best served by simply creating a transparent view or button that responds to touch and placing that above the bar area for your UINavigationController.  This transparent view could then catch touch events intended for the entire bar area.

However, I'd think really hard about what you're trying to achieve with this.  Overriding the standard user interactions from a built-in interface element may lead to user frustration and even potential rejection by Apple.

Comment: In principle you're right, but in this particular appliance I'd say a category is fine. Nicolas doesn't seem to be too experienced with Cocoa Touch, judging by the drawRect:-method there is little other functionality to mess up, and subclassing UINavigationBar is _quite_ tricky, in my experience.

Comment: Ok great! I'll see what i can do with both answers. 
PS. im not experienced with Cocoa Touch.. I do my best though.

Comment: @eliego - In this case, subclassing is not needed.  He simply can put a transparent view or button over the navigation bar portion of the screen and have that handle the touches.  Advocating a practice that Apple explicitly warns about is not the right way to get a new developer started on the platform.  You want people to build good habits when they are first learning the environment.

Comment: OK, im done with this one! Thanks Brad and eliego! I finally just added an imageView as a subview to the uinavbar, added tint and removed the category. works really good, but not touch-handling. I wont use it because i cant get to add a uibutton as a subview instead, i shows up but it wont do anything, not even highlight. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding these three functions in your category: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006783-CH4-SW13

Comment: Thanks ill give it a try and come back!

Comment: Ok, so im supposed to use this 3 functions:  

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

im pretty new to how overriding works, so please be nice.. Do i have to write my code inside, or do i have to do something with the params too?  
Thanks for the quick reply!  


edit: ok i give up, dont know how to add a code tag in a comment here..

Comment: Start by just implementing them in your category (the exact same way as you have done with drawRect:), and output some NSLog to understand how they are called. In the end you will probably only have to add code to the touchesEnded:-method, and there perform whatever action you want.

Comment: OK great! Thanks. by the way ill leave the question open so i can get back to you if i have any problem.

Comment: A category is not the right place to locate custom touch handling code.  See my answer for more.